# How to add Caldroid in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to create a caldroid calendar in a fragment.

However I'm getting an error what am I doing wrong? I have a sliding menu (not abs) and it seems to be causing the error i think.

I've included the the xml and class that's being called from the main fragment below along with the log cat. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class PM_Fragment extends Fragment{
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pm_fragment, container, false);

        CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = fragManager.beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.pm_fragment, caldroidFragment);
        t.commit();

    return rootView;
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<fragment
   android:name="com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.PM_Fragment"
   android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): Process: com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning, PID: 11536
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class fragment
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.CalendarFragment.onCreateView(CalendarFragment.java:29)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.BaseActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.PM_Fragment.onAttach(PM_Fragment.java:22)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4972)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
05-29 00:50:00.382: E/AndroidRuntime(11536):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: What does this LogCat line suggest you `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.BaseActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @DerGolem If i knew I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: It should suggest you that `com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.BaseActivity` should extend  **FragmentActivity** instead of **Activity**.

Comment: Base activity is the activity the sliding drawers are built on top of. I do not wish to modify it I only wish to have the caldoid built upon an existing fragment

Comment: So, if you really don't want to change the extended type of your main Activity (which then **won't contain Fragments**), you must start a new Activity which extends **FragmentActivity** and use that one to **contain your Fragment**.

Comment: The method i was trying to implement was an embedded fragment and what you purpose will not work with a sliding menu with all fragments. Theres gotta be another way like the documentation suggest of using embedded fragments so i can keep my fragments.

Comment: If you're targetting older OS versions (< API Level 11), you must extend FragmentActivity, to embed your Fragments. Otherwise, you can estend Activity (since Fragment support is already built in in newer API Level Activities).

Comment: I'm not, so just extend activity in PM_fragment?

Comment: It should work. But! The exception tells you something about the support library - why are you including that one, if you don't support older OS versions? I think there's a weird commistion between old and new which isn't mixing well. It may happen, when your project is a patchwork of things taken here and there.

Comment: what do you mean? I just want a nicer calendar...

Comment: OK, the problem is the opposite: It's CalDroid which is supporting older devices (it has been thought for adding the CalendarView to pre-14 devices). So, you may want to **rewrite Caldroid to natively support 14+** (`remove the support library and its imports, chage getSupprtFragment to getFragment, change FragmentActivity to Activity, ...`), ...

Comment: Ok lets start over, their documentation leads you to believe there would be an easy way of embedding their calendar into a fragment. Is there, besides the method i was trying?

Comment: I don't know. They say this: `Caldroid can be used with Android 2.2 and above.` and you have an issue while embedding an Activity which extends FragmentActivity, because of the support library. My "easy" solution is **A** - To transform YOUR app an make it available to older devices, or **B** - To transform CalDroid and make it work to your needs (I'd probably embed Caldroid into my app - giving the credits to roomOrama in the help file, of course)

Comment: Dang I'm just trying to get caldroid on a fragment why is that so difficult.

Comment: May I ask you why is CalDroid so appealing? For us, who want to support older devices and miss a CalendarView, it's OK to look at it. But you could use the CalendarView and probably can customize **that one**, no need to complicate your life without a real reason...

Comment: The calendar view seems to be quite slow to load when transitioning between fragments and i only want to show the current month with options to scroll through months with buttons on the top like caldroid rather than the way calendar view does it with the swiping down

Comment: Maybe the CalendarView isn't the culprit? Anyway, see what I found (I gave it just a superficial sight, but it seems promising): http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html

Comment: I've used it before and its not bad...

Comment: So you're looking for something just **better**. Keep this as a **fallback**, if your research fails.

Answer (score 2):

I was checking the sample on git and they user a linearLayout for the example instead your

Your xml layout:

```
<fragment
   android:name="com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.PM_Fragment"
   android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Caldroid Sample layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Where i get the info:
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/blob/master/demo/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FrameLayout instead of fragment